# NumPy array of bytes that does not remove the trailing zeros

Tags: python, numpy, serialization

How can I create a NumPy array of bytes that does not remove the trailing zeros? `np.bytes_` and `np.str_` remove the trailing zeros. `np.void` requires that every element of the array have the same length. Is there any dtype that can contain blob of bytes with trailing zeros and variable length?

```py
>>> np.array([b'\x00', b'\x01\x00'], np.void)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Invalid type promotion with void datatypes of different lengths. Use the `np.bytes_` datatype instead to pad the shorter value with trailing zero bytes.
>>> np.array([b'\x00', b'\x01\x00'], np.bytes_)
array([b'', b'\x01'], dtype='|S2')
>>> np.array([b'\x00', b'\x01\x00'], np.str_)
array(['', '\x01'], dtype='<U2')
>>> np.array([b'\x00', b'\x01\x00'], np.object_)
array([b'\x00', b'\x01\x00'], dtype=object)
```

While `np.object_` works, the serialization is not appropriate for my use case, because it serializes the pointers instead of the actual underlying byte array.

Comment: Why are you using `np.void`?  I've seen such a dtype when creating structure arrays, but have never used it directly.

Comment: @hpaulj Because it does not remove the trailing zeros. It clearly didn't work, since it cannot work with variable-length arrays.

Comment: `numpy` does not have any variable length `dtype`.  That is impossible given how data is stored and processed.